# An Upper Bound for an $[n,k,d]$ Linear Binary Code.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, upper-lower-bounds, coding-theory, binary

I've been reading about the various upper bounds for different types of codes. Recently, I came across a statement that is similar to the Singleton Upper Bound that I am having trouble proving. The statement is as follows.

> Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an $[n, k, d]$ linear binary code. If $k \geq 5$ and $d \geq 3$, then $k \leq n - d - 1$.

My strategy has been to assume $k > n - d - 1$ and arrive at a contradiction using the fact that $d \geq 3$ and $k \geq 5$, but I'm not having any luck.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**EDIT**

Instead of my original strategy, I've been looking at the $k \times n$ generator matrix $G$ of $\mathcal{C}$ in standard form along with the $(n-k) \times n$ parity check matrix $H$ and using the fact that $d \geq 3$ means that the columns in $H$ are nonzero and distinct. Since $H$ has $n-k$ rows, then it can have at most $2^{n-k} - 1$ columns. I haven't been able to make any progress from this point using the fact that $k \geq 5$.

Comment: The $[8,4,4]$ extended binary Hamming code and the $[n,n-1,2]$ single parity check code show that the bound does not hold if $k < 5$ or $d < 3$.

Comment: Thanks Dilip. I was also able to find similar counter-examples to show that the bound doesn't hold for $d < 3$ and $k < 5$. I am having trouble showing that it will always hold for $d \geq 3$ and $k \geq 5$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C$ be a binary linear $[n,k,d]$ code with $k \geq 5$ and $d \geq 3$.

For $d=3$ the Hamming bound gives us $(n+1)\cdot q^k \leq q^n$. Hence $k \leq n - \lceil \log_2(n+1)\rceil$. For $n \leq 7$ this is a contradiction to $k \geq 5$. For $n \geq 8$ this implies $k \leq n - \lceil \log_2 9\rceil = n - 4 = n - d - 1$.

For $d=4$, puncturing in a single position gives a $[n-1,k,3]$ code. As in the above case, the Hamming bound leads to $k \leq n - 1 - \lceil \log_2 n\rceil$. For $n\leq 8$, this is a contradiction to $k \geq 5$. For all $n \geq 9$, we get $k \leq n - 1 - \lceil\log_2 9\rceil = n - 1 - 4 = n - d - 1$.

For $d \geq 5$, the Griesmer bound gives
$$
n \geq \sum_{i=1}^k \lceil d/2^i\rceil \geq d + 3 + \underbrace{1 + \ldots + 1}_{k-2\text{ times}} = k + d + 1
\quad\implies\quad k \leq n - d - 1.$$

Comment: If a linear binary $[n,k,4]$ is extended by adding ab overall parity check bit, we don't get a $[n+1,k,5]$ code because the original codewords of weight $4$ have parity bit $0$ and so they remain of weight $4$ in the extended code.  You need to tighten the argument here a little, or use a different approach.

Comment: @DilipSarwate very true... Thanks for catching this. I will try to give a correction. (Hamming should still be the way to go for $d=4$, but there will be a few extra cases I guess.)

Comment: @DilipSarwate o.k. there is the correction. It was not hard.

Comment: OK.  +1.  Thanks for answering an 11-year old question.

Comment: @DilipSarwate thank you :) Interesting questions are never old...